# ng-view not getting updated when there is ng-grid inside it

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, ng-view

Please take a look at following plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/34JedA
It is a simple app with a ng-grid. What I need to do is navigate to the edit page when the edit button is clicked. What happens is instead of going to the edit page columns in the grid get messed up. Could anyone please explain why it is happening and what I could do to correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the ng-grid version you are using, I changed to the latest version I found and it worked.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-grid/2.0.8/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/5myA2K?p=preview

Comment: Damn, it's the kind of bug I could spend two hours hunting for. Thanks! The bad thing is that 2.0.9 seems to be affected as well.

Comment: For curious, this commit fixes it: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/commit/52de35530360d51425ccbd472e9f068424f487dd

Answer (score 0):

Do not include file with following header.

```
/***********************************************
* ng-grid JavaScript Library

* Compiled At: 04/22/2014 16:27
***********************************************/
```

instead of this, please add

```
/***********************************************
* ng-grid JavaScript Library

* Compiled At: 04/07/2014 16:55
***********************************************/
```